# Trying to create a image menu with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an image menu with bootstrap for a portfolio website. But the navigation is highly flawed, how can I resolve this?

https://codepen.io/wouter0102/pen/XoGaEe

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).parents('.accordion').find('.collapse.show')) {
    var idx = $(this).index('[data-toggle="collapse"]');
    if (idx == $('.collapse.show').index('.collapse')) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.button a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.button a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.collapsing {
  transition: height 0.6s;
}

.collapse {
  height: 30em;
  background-image: url(https://media4.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2017_02/1186900/cute-baby-names-parenting-today-tease-170109_30c48f2b22f1e8ad95773edb635f0085.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.collapse p {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 25em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="main">
  <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div id="Newbornpix" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed quae, reprehenderit ex, dolorum tempora enim sequi dolor aliquam, rerum quos maxime soluta. Quos quas at voluptas ipsam, ea! Ab, fuga.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Newbornbutton" class="collapsed button">
      <a href="#Newbornpix" data-toggle="collapse">NEWBORN</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Geboortepix" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, veniam ipsum ut ad, incidunt veritatis, culpa qui dolorum odio et recusandae quod quisquam rerum saepe libero sed commodi laborum repudiandae.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Geboortebutton" class="collapsed button">
      <a href="#Geboortepix" data-toggle="collapse">GEBOORTE</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Portretpix" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet asperiores laborum voluptatum facilis voluptates assumenda beatae maxime nobis aliquid ullam natus modi saepe commodi, inventore repellat ad qui! Quasi, iure.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Portretbutton" class="collapsed button">
      <a href="#Portretpix" data-toggle="collapse">PORTRET</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Contact" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque dolorem aperiam pariatur eos vitae molestias, ipsam quasi iusto repellat expedita similique sequi quas ex quisquam porro nemo distinctio explicabo. Magni!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="Contactbutton" class="collapsed button">
      <a href="#Contact" data-toggle="collapse">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  /* always keep at least 1 open by preventing the current to close itself */
  $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parents('.accordion').find('.collapse.show')) {
      var idx = $(this).index('[data-toggle="collapse"]');
      if (idx == $('.collapse.show').index('.collapse')) {
        // prevent collapse
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

EDIT
So what I mean by that it is flawed, if you look at the codepen link you see that the transitions aren't fluid and that the collapsed tekst has to jump to it's location. You see that it starts at a position and then jumps to it's position where it needs to be. Also if the transition is happening you see it expanding nicely for 1 sec or so and then it jumps to fully expanded. When trying to expand a section that is positioned above another section the section underneath will jump up for a halve second and then go back down. I also want to be the style of the links when I expand them to be different and overlapping the background image, how do I go about doing this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific on the "flaws"? What is it that you're trying to achieve? or an image of the design that you want it to look like

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different jQuery libraries, one in your `<head>` and one at the bottom of the page. They are preventing each other from running (the $ is being reassigned by the second library). Remove either and your code works fine. Alternately, you can use jQuery [noConflict(true)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) from the second lib to use both. However, this is not recommended.